# Tuxedo Integration with JBoss AS-7 using JCA

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jca, tuxedo

Currently I'm looking for solution to integrate Tuxedo with JBoss AS-7 using JCA which provided by the oracle. I downloaded the com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter.rar file from oracle. deployed it into **jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments**.

After adding this I've added below in **jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml** in *subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"*

```xml
<resource-adapter>  
    <archive>com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter.rar</archive>
    <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
    <connection-definitions>
        <connection-definition class-name="com.oracle.tuxedo.adapter.spi.TuxedoManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/jca/tuxedo" enabled="true" use-java-context="false"/>
    </connection-definitions>
</resource-adapter>
```

Now, after adding this I'm getting below error when I'm starting the app server,

```
14:50:20,642 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployer."com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployer."com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter": JBAS010446: Failed to start RA deployment [com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:103)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056: Deployment failed: file:/D:/Development/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp315113f896878c83/com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter.rar-2388b49206abf85a/contents/
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:2179)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1034)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AS7RaDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:173)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:100)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.validator.ValidatorException: Severity: ERROR
Section: 19.4.2
Description: A ResourceAdapter must implement a "public int hashCode()" method.
Code: com.oracle.tuxedo.adapter.TuxedoFBCResourceAdapter

    ... 9 more

14:50:20,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

I tried to fixed all the possible ways but unable to fix. I think I'm missing some configuration with Jboss/tuxedo. Can you guys help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Ashish Mishra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable RAR-validation with jboss-cli:

```
/subsystem=jca/archive-validation=archive-validation:write-attribute(name=enabled, value=false)
```

Comment: I have successfully completed the tuxedo integration with Jboss AS. I have  explained in detail in this blog

http://akmishra30.blogspot.com/2016/05/j2ee-integration-with-oracle-tuxedo.html